# Отловить нажатие на Canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas

Можно-ли каким-либо способом отловить нажатие на канву и начать её двигать мышкой?
Канва же не имеет обработчиков событий сама по себе.

Нужно из разных графических элементов собирать фигурки.

`Shape` не очень подходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно же и TImage использовать, рисовать все что необходимо на этом холсте и перемещать обрабатывая **OnMouseDown** и **OnMouseMove**:

```
//Объявляем глобальные переменные (сразу извиняюсь Дельфей нет под рукой, буду писать кусками )) )

var  
Hitign: boolean;  
xNew,yNew: integer;

Hiting:=false; // это прописываем в FormCreate

//это в ImageMouseDown
Hiting:=true;  
xNew:=X; yNew:=Y;

//это в ImageMouseMove
if Hiting then
begin
left:=left+(x-xNew);
top:=top+(y-yNew);
end;

//да и про MouseUp надо не забыть
Hiting:=false;
```

**UPD**
Кстати рисуя отдельные фигурки на канве, надо будет определять попали ли мы в область фигурки или промахнулись (для того чтобы переместить ее)

Comment: как вы себе представляете собирание фигурок из разных объектов TImage? Они же будут перекрывать друг друга.  

А если все рисовать на одном Timage, то и двигаться будет все вместе, и никакую фигурку точно не соберете.

Comment: TransparentColor

Comment: велосипедисты) стоит помоему обрабатывать мыш у родителя и делать с обьектами все что вам вздумается)